# How should timezones be formatted In Matlab, when inserting a string into a postgresql field timestamp with time zone?

Tags: matlab, postgresql, datetime

I have no problems inserting strings of format 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' into a timestamp with time zone field in my PostgreSQL database using the Matlab `datainsert` function. However, I can't seem to work out how to include a time zone in the string itself, so Postgres assumes that it has the timezone of my locale.

For example

```
create table tmp_test (
id serial primary key,
time timestamp with time zone NOT NULL
);
```

Then, this works:

```
datainsert(conn, 'tmp_test', {'time'}, {'2016-09-15 03:45:49.326'})
```

but this doesn't:

```
>> datainsert(conn, 'tmp_test', {'time'}, {'2016-09-15 03:45:49.326 +00:00'})
Error using database/datainsert (line 301)
Unable to insert element in row 1 column 1, 2016-09-15 03:45:49.326 +00:00. Timestamp format must be yyyy-mm-dd
hh:mm:ss[.fffffffff]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i insert timestamp with timezone in postgresql with prepared statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676168/how-can-i-insert-timestamp-with-timezone-in-postgresql-with-prepared-statement)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming Unix(?) is the environment, but the date() command can return a string with the timezone included: i.e., for Eastern Time EDT

```
 $> TZ='America/New_York' date +%Y-%m-%d_%T_%Z
 2016-09-15_01:34:10_EDT
```

Was this for a specific language used with PostgreSQL, like PHP, etc?

Comment: thanks. The environment is actually Windows 7. I am inserting via commands like: `insert into tmp_test(time) values ('2016-08-01 14:22:50.333')`.

Comment: Then officially, I refer ya to the specific postgres documentation for date formats: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

Comment: thanks, it turns out that this is Matlab specific. I can insert strings with time zones from pgadmin but not in Matlab

Comment: I am afraid that the documentation does not give me any insights on how to insert time zones. However, this seems to work: `insert into tmp_test(time) values ('2016-08-01 14:22:50.333 +00:00')`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is with the Java connector from Matlab. Someone else relying on this had the same problem:

[How can i insert timestamp with timezone in postgresql with prepared statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676168/how-can-i-insert-timestamp-with-timezone-in-postgresql-with-prepared-statement?rq=1)

Unfortunately this probably means that there is no high level way to get Matlab to do this insert for you, you must rely on low level commands like:

```
exec(conn, 'insert into tmp_test (time) VALUES (''2016-09-16 16:03:37.313 +00:00'')')
```